# How to add dependencies in gradle file in android for Firebase for database and auth together?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-gradle-plugin, firebase-authentication

I am extremely new to android and trying the firebase where i am trying out firebase auth and firebase database.

I could successfully complete the auth functionality and below is the gradle file contents for app module just after it.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.cirvi.laxmimobileshopee"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.1'


    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.0.2"

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Now for the next step i want to use firebase database in the same project and i update the gradle file by adding the  dependency

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.6.1'
```

As soon as i do it and start the sync i get the following error

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies]
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 9.6.1.
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 2.86 secs
Information:1 error
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

Below is the code for my project gradle file.

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I tried to update the google service version in the project gradle file but then ran into other issues. As i am new to android and trying things out i am stuck and not able to figure out currently how to resolve this. Can anyone guide me or help me?

[image: project Structure]

Comment: Have you added `google-services.json` that Firebase generated for your project?

Comment: Yes i have added it . I could complete the firebase auth successfully

Comment: Clean and Rebuild your project.

Comment: download fresh `google-services.json` file from `firebase` console and paste it in your project

Comment: @Ninja I added the fresh google-services.json  and then also tried to clean /build but getting the same error again

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

Go to project level `build.gradle` & check if it looks exactly like this:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```

set same dependency for both

```
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.6.1"
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.6.1'
```

Comment: I do not have the maven part, but making dependencies point to same version 9.6.1 helped me solve the issue

Answer (score 3):

Try this:
**Build > Edit Libraries and Dependencies...**

[image]
[image]

---

Now, search for **available** modules:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the same versions of firebase. 
You used version 9.0.2 of auth and 9.6.1 of database.

Also I suggest to use the latest version of the firebase SDK

Add

```
com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.4
com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.4
```

Comment: i tried the above but then i get a new error  Error:(31, 13) Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.4
Error:Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.4
Error:(32, 13) Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.4

Answer (score 0):

```
Add this dependency from your needs

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
```